# how can I search for a string in a folder that has zip files also

Tags: unix, search, putty, grep, zip

I am trying to search a string in a folder "test".

This folder has sub folders and zip files too. I want to search within this directory to find the match.

I used

```
zgrep '11:57' test
zgrep '11:57' test
```

But I could not got the result.

can some one tell the exact command for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the files you want to be checked so in this case you should use:

```
zgrep '11:57' test/*
```

But you also want sub-directories. For this you need to include the `find`-command.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep '11:57'
```

**Edit**: I didn't use the `find -exec cmd {}` option here because according to [this blog](http://danielmiessler.com/blog/linux-xargs-vs-exec#.UmgSRflWZr8) and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896808/find-exec-cmd-vs-xargs) `-exec` runs a separate instance of your command for every find. Especially with lots of files this is not efficient. One pipe to `xargs` and `xargs` makes sure it runs your command  as few times as possible *which is often just once*.

Comment: +1 but this command can be improved by using ... find -type -f -exec zgrep '11:57' {} \;  The option -f restricts the match to files, and there is no need for a pipe

Comment: I especially didn't specify the `-exec` option (and used `xargs`) because i read somewhere that with the `-exec` option `zgrep` is executed separate for **every** file/directory. With the `xargs` it should be executed only once. (I could be wrong here?)

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yep. [Here](http://danielmiessler.com/blog/linux-xargs-vs-exec) it was. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896808/find-exec-cmd-vs-xargs).